# How to access responseText from response in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, response, browserify

```
    var $ = require('jquery'),
        Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        mainJs = require('./main');


var services = {



    authenticationservice: function(collections) {
         var jsonreturn;

         var api_token = mainJs.get_api_token();


        jsonreturn = collections.fetch({

        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_token.access_token},
        success: function (collection, response, options) {

           var responsejson = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
           return responsejson;

        },

        error: function (collection,response,options){

            var errorjson = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            //alert(errorjson.error_description);
             return errorjson;

        }
    });

        return jsonreturn; 



    }

};




module.exports = services;
```

How do i access the responseText from jsonreturn please help?

Comment: the behavior of `collections.fetch` is asynchronous and expects callbacks. In your case, you have already registered that using success and error. But the problem is with the service itself as it doesn't accept callbacks which will be used inside the success and error. The `jsonreturn` wont have meaningful value. You should change your service API.

Comment: Would overriding the Backbone.sync be better in this case?

Comment: No, I wouldn't recommend that. It will be an anti-pattern.

Comment: What should i change it to then?

Comment: 1) Possible [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what do you want to do with that response? 2) As the other commentor said, `fetch()` uses `$.ajax()` which is asynchroneous. The return value of `$.ajax()` (and thus the return value of `fetch()`) is an XHR object and does not contain the response data _until the response arrived_. You will have to register a "resolver" on the promise of that XHR object like: `fetch().promise().done(function(data){ console.log("Data:", data);  });` (but this is still asyncroneous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `collections.fetch` is asynchronous in behavior, you should return jQuery deferred as a call to `authenticationservice` function. Refer below code

```
authenticationservice : function(){
  var def = $.Deferred();
  ...
  //Somewhere in success
  success: function(...){
    def.resolve(responsejson);
  }
  ...
  //Somewhere in error
  error:function(...){
    def.reject(errorjson);
  }
  ...
  return def;
}
```

Now the place from where you are calling this service must be aligned to deal with promise like below

```
service.authenticationservice().then(
  function(responsejson){
    //Do processing in case of success.
  },
  function(errorjson){
    //Do processing in case of failure
  }
);
```

For more details on [JQuery Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/).